# Smart contract panicked: The account faucet.xx.testnet is not registered

Tags: nearprotocol, near

I have a faucet token contract named "faucet.xxx.testnet" and there is a minting method where I would mint some tokens to my near wallet "m2.testnet" account and do a call back at the same time in the contract.
However, after calling to the minting method from m2.testnet, I always get the msg "that account faucet.xx.testnet is not registered". I don't understand what is wrong with this contract.

```
#[ext_contract(ext_ft_contract)]
pub trait FungibleTokenCore {
    fn ft_transfer(&mut self, receiver_id: AccountId, amount: U128, memo: Option<String>);
}

pub fn faucet_token(&mut self, amount: U128) -> Promise {
      
        let account_id: AccountId = env::predecessor_account_id();
        ext_ft_contract::ft_transfer(
            account_id.clone(), 
            amount, 
            Some(String::from("Faucet by MD Dev")), 
            &self.ft_contract_id, 
            1, 
            FT_TRANSFER_GAS
        )
        .then(ext_self::ft_transfer_callback(
            amount, 
            account_id.clone(), 
            &env::current_account_id(), 
            0, 
            FAUCET_CALLBACK_GAS
        ))
   

 #[private]
    pub fn ft_transfer_callback(&mut self, amount: U128, account_id: AccountId) {
        let mut account_balance: Balance = self.accounts.get(&account_id).unwrap_or_else(|| 0);
        if account_balance == 0 {
            self.total_account_shared += 1;
        }

        account_balance += amount.0;

        self.accounts.insert(&account_id,&account_balance);
        self.total_shared += amount.0;

        if self.total_balance_share > amount.0 {
            self.total_balance_share -= amount.0;
        }
    }
```

```
Scheduling a call: faucet.xx.testnet.faucet_token({"amount":"1000000000"})
Doing account.functionCall()
Receipts: 5aHoX36TLbgpUhkLibCRB7uaNsy79go2ZY86QbC4WnFK, 2MFeD2yJB7yQ7DPKuoZSk3fbUNH3XpPUiAazhWZoa3Do
    Failure [faucet.xx.testnet]: Error: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: The account faucet.xx.testnet is not registered"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must deposit money into the contract for both sending and receiving accounts to register to be able to transfer token.
Use command:

```
near call CONTRACT_ID storage_deposit --accountId ACCOUNT_ID --depositYocto MINIMUM_STORAGE_BALANCE
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9kiE.png)
See more at: [NEP141](https://github.com/near/NEPs/discussions/145)